# how to use 2 classes as a generic method's parameters

Tags: c#, class, generics, methods

I'want to learn how can I use 2 classes as a generic method parameters. Let me explain.

```
    public class A
    {
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
    public class B
    {
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
        
       static void Main(string[] args) 
      { 
        A PersonA = new A();
        B PersonB = new B();
        PersonA.age = 15;
        PersonB.age = 10; 
        
      }
```

How can I create a generic method that can subtract the `AGEs` depends on my call?

- If I call `PersonA` first and `PersonB` second, return result should be 5.
- Or if I call `PersonB` first and `PersonA` second, then the return result should be -5.

These are just an example, I just have simplified to explain myself because I have wrote 2 methods but these 2 methods do the same job except class names and I want to do that job with a single generic method.

Comment: didn't get you. why cant you use a simple method like `int GetResult(int a, int b){return a-b;}`

Comment: No, I just want to learn how to use generics with 2 other classes. As I said before,  I just have simplified to explain myself, so I dont want to learn how to create that method. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refactor your classes and then use a generic constraint:

First, refactor like so:

```
interface IAge
{
   int Age { get; }
}

public class A : IAge
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class B : IAge
{
   int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can define a method that has a generic constraint:

```
public static int Subtract<T>(T a, T b) where T : IAge
{
    return a.Age - b.Age;
}
```

To use:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IAge a = new A() { Age = 5; }
    IAge b = new B() { Age = 10; }

    int result = Subtract(a, b) // -5
}
```

Comment: Can I refactor by using Interfaces  instead of Abstracts? Will I need to change rest of it?

Comment: Yes you can use interfaces instead. Generic type constraints will still work with interfaces. I've modified the code respectively.